# Verificación de comentarios

Tags: php

Necesito ayuda con este código. Tengo que hacer una verificación de comentarios para una pagina.

Mi idea es que cuando entre un comentario, se verifique si se repite, pero hay un problema, todo el tiempo dice que se repite el comentario.

Quiero pedirles ayuda en que error tengo, ya que yo ya no lo encuentro. Acá les dejo el código:

```
<?php
$error = false;

if(empty($_POST['comentario']))
{
    $error['comentario'] = "comentario requerido";
}

if(!($_POST['comentario']==$_POST['comentario2']))
{
    $error['comentario'] = "El comentario ya existe";
    $error['comentario2'] = "El comentario ya existe";
}


if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    $sql_duplicado = "SELECT id 
                        FROM comentarios 
                        WHERE comentario = '".$_POST['comentario']."'"; 


    $res_duplicado = ejecutar_query($conex, $sql_duplicado);
    $com_encontrado = mysqli_num_rows($res_duplicado);

    if($com_encontrado!=0){
        $error['comentario'] = "comentario duplicado";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: No se si soy yo, pero no logro visualizar el código..

Comment: @AndressBlend faltaba formato a la pregunta, ya se agregó el código, saludos!

Comment: Esta validación if(!($_POST['comentario']==$_POST['comentario2'])) con el signo ! estás negando lo que está dentro del parentesis, entonces queda como "si los comentarios no son iguales" entonces siempre va a dar false si son diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Es por que en este if:

```
if(!($_POST['comentario']==$_POST['comentario2']))
{
    $error['comentario'] = "El comentario ya existe";
    $error['comentario2'] = "El comentario ya existe";
}
```

tienes una negación antes de preguntar si comentario es igual a comentario2 y termina evaluando si son diferentes.

intenta así:

```
if($_POST['comentario'] == $_POST['comentario2'])
{
    $error['comentario'] = "El comentario ya existe";
    $error['comentario2'] = "El comentario ya existe";
}
```